# Where to find church records for Niedersachsen / Nordstemmen

Tags: germany, church-records

I have a subscription to https://www.archion.de (a selection of german church records) but I cannot find records for the town of Barnten, which I would expect to find in an archive for Niedersachsen / Nordstemmen. This area seems to be missing completely from their digital service.

Does anybody know the whereabouts of the church archive that I am looking for and if this is accessible from the Internet somehow?

**Update**: Logically, Barnten should be part of "Landeskirchliches Archiv Hannover, Kirchenkreis Laatzen-Pattensen" as neighboring towns such as "Rössing" (to the South) and "Pattensen" (to the North) are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Archion about this and their answer is that the books I am looking for are in Sarstedt and not available in digital format.

There are plans to digitalize the archive. However, there is no time frame set.

Comment: Their original response:

Die Aufzeichnungen des Ortes Barnten sind in den Kirchenbüchern von Sarstedt enthalten.
Die Digitalisierung des Ortes Sarstedt ist geplant, aber noch nicht zeitlich fixiert.

Comment: Update: I asked them again about this and the work has still not been done as of 2020-06-21.

Answer (score 3):

The State archives at https://www.arcinsys.niedersachsen.de/arcinsys/ provide a search engine that gives access to 478 entries when searching for "Barnten". You'll have to determine if any of this might pertain to your research time period, etc.

Comment: This might be precisely what I am looking for. However, I'm having some trouble finding. I'm interested in birth records in Barnten for the year 1792 and census information for this area from around this time period. Even though the website can be viewed in English the archives / document titles are in German which makes it more difficult for me to determine if they indeed contain the information that I am looking for.